# Problems using pgr_fromAtoB - postgresql error

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I have some trouble with the pgr_fromAtoB function of the workshop.
I get:

```
ERROR:  column "ways" does not exist
```

But "ways" is the table, not a column. What am I do wrong?
My table ways looks like:

```
Table "public.ways"
Column  |           Type            |    Modifiers
----------+---------------------------+----------------------------------------------------
gid      | integer                   | not null default                 nextval('ways_gid_seq'::regclass)
__gid    | numeric(10,0)             |
class_id | numeric(10,0)             |
type     | character varying(23)     |
length   | numeric                   |
name     | character varying(40)     |
osm_id   | character varying(14)     |
the_geom | geometry(MultiLineString) |
source   | integer                   |
target   | integer                   |
Indexes:
"ways_gid_idx" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (gid)
"source_idx" btree (source)
"target_idx" btree (target)
"ways_source_idx" btree (source)
"ways_target_idx" btree (target)
"ways_the_geom_gidx" gist (the_geom)
```

Comment: The functioned is a stored procedure and the error may be misleading. It's not really clear to me, why this error happens, but looking at your table I can see that your geometry is "MULTILINESTRING", which is either not necessary, or if you really have multi-geometries, it's a problem. It's better to make sure, that your geometry is LINESTRING. Eventually that's the issue.